# I have a multi-page website using aws-amplify running on multiple servers with pm2. I cannot get the site to keep users logged in

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, aws-amplify

I have an express server serving multiple pages where some need authentication. I'm running pm2 with 8 servers. I am using @aws-amplify/auth on the server and I am saving the token in cookies.  I have middleware that retrieves the cooke and adds an Authorization header before navigating to secure pages.  the currentAuthenticatedUser() method isn't using the header.  it returns not signed in. How do I either send the authorization header with express properly or use the correct method on the server for authentication?

Express middleware to set header from cookie

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.key;
  // console.log('isAuthorized', token);
  if (token) {
    console.log('Found Authorization header');
    req.headers['Authorization'] = `${token}`;
  }
  next();
});
```

Express route to set cookie when successfully signed in

```
router.post('/signin', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (!username || !password) {
    return res.sendStatus(403);
  }

  await Auth.signIn(username, password)
        .then(user => {
          const token = user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;
          res.cookie('key', token, { maxAge: (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000), httpOnly: true });
          console.log('set token');
          res.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(403);
        });

});
```

Express route to return authorized users

```
const isAuthorized = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('headers', Boolean(req.headers.Authorization));
  await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(user => {
      console.log('signed in');
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Not signed in', err);
      res.redirect(302, '/login');
    });
}
```

My expected result is when a user signs in I would like their signin status to be maintained using valid jwt tokens.

Comment: Where are you storing session data?

Comment: I'm only storing the token in cookies.

Comment: AWS Amplify uses a system of three tokens (id token, access token and refresh token). You might need to get new tokens using the refresh token.